# How to map one error to a different error with RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Is it possible to map the error type with RxSwift?

For example, I have a helper function like this:

```
enum InternalError: Error {
   case fooError
   case barError
}

private func helper() -> Observable<MyData> {
    // ... 
}

enum ServiceError: Error {
    case fatalError(message: String)
    case warning(message: String)
}
```

I am hoping that we can do sth like this, notice the following `mapError` doesn't exist:

```
func getData() -> Observable<MyData> {
    helper().mapError({ error: InternalError -> ServiceError
        switch error {
            case .fooError: 
                return ServiceError.fatalError(message: "This is bad.")
            case .barError:
                return ServiceError.warning(message: "Be careful.")
        }
    })
}
```

Is it possible? Or is it a bad idea in general?

Answer (score 2):

What you described in you problem is impossible to do by **returning** an error because the return type of your function is an `Observable<MyData>`. There are two solutions:

You could define a `enum Result<T>` with `.success(T)` and `.error(Swift.Error)` and return `Observable<Result<MyData>>` where you would handle your errors as follows:

```
helper().catchError{ error in
            guard let error = error as? InternalError else { throw UnknownError() }
            switch error {
                case .fooError:
                    return Observable.just(
                        Result.error(
                            ServiceError.fatalError(message: "This is bad.")
                        )
                    )
                case .barError:
                    return Observable.just(
                        Result.error(
                            ServiceError.warning(message: "Be careful.")
                        )
                    )
            }
        }
```

Or you could simply rethrow by substituting `return Observable...` with a `throw` which I personally think is better than a `Result<T>` overhead.